# perform contains operation for hashtable

Tags: java, vector, hashtable

I have a hashtable "listUserEvents' which is of the form string,vector. I am trying to see if the hashtable has some data for the given string or not.

```
listUserEvents = getUserInfo();
for (int i = 0; i < compareEventData.size(); i++) {
          EventData eventForExistingDate = (EventData) compareEventData.elementAt(i);
//here i want to check if listUserEvents  the hashtable has eventForExistingDate.getSummary() for string "hello"
}
```

how to perform this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you just want:

```
if (listUserEvents.containsKey("hello"))
{
    ...
}
```

Your description isn't very clear though, as now we're not using `eventForExistingDate`...

Note that if you use generic collections, you're unlikely to need the cast in the previous line.

Comment: listUserEvents=getUserInfo();
  Enumeration e = listUserEvents.keys();
  Vector value = null ;
  while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    value = (Vector) listUserEvents.get(compareKey);

  }

Comment: i want to check if the hashtable has value for the key "hello"

Comment: @harqs: Okay, edited - but it's not clear where `eventForExistingDate` comes in now...